# Is there a way to get a compile time constant CulutureInfo?

Tags: c#, default-parameters, iformatprovider

I have a method that is used to format some value with a given format string and an `IFormatProvider`. The signature is:

```cs
public static string FormatParameter(object parameterValue, string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
```

I want that the formatProvider is by default the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, but

```cs
public static string FormatParameter(object parameterValue, string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

produces a compile error:

```
CS1736 | Default parameter value for 'formatProvider' must be a compile-time constant
```

Is there a way to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or someother standard `IFormatProvider` as an default parameter value? Or do I just have to check at runtime that `formatProvider` is `null` and then use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: Make the default `null`. Then the first line of code will be `formatProvider = formatProvider ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`.

Comment: @mjwills so I **have** to use runtime checks, there is noway around that?

Comment: Correct. Just like the error says.